# Is there a way to set size for maximized windows in Unity?

Tags: unity, window

[image: Chromium browser back button covered by dash popping up]First, before anyone says anything, I looked at the similar questions before going ahead with this. Is there a way to control your maximum size (width/height) of a window when maximized? The entire reason is I use my browser maximized (strange its the only application I do it with), and its annoying to have the unity panel popup most of the time when I go to click back. Any ideas?

Edit: added screenshot

Comment: I run Firefox full screen and Unity doesn't pop up when I click the "back" button?  Can you elaborate, perhaps with a screenshot, on what you're seeing?

Comment: Either set your launcher to never hide, or increase the delay (you can set both in CompizConfig Settings Manager).

Comment: As a work around, you could either adjust toolbar (view -> toolbars -> customize) and add in a space or flexible space. alternately use the keyboard (Alt Left arrow).

Comment: Alright thanks bodhi, I didn't know the new back shortcut (used to backspace haha) I prefer using keyboard when possible so again thanks and ill keep that one

Comment: You can easily re-enable the backspase action in `about:config`. The preference name is `browser.backspace_action`, and its value should be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but if you want to maximize your window with specific size(width/height) like mac then it not possible usually. But i have a solution for your unity panel and browser problem.
I hope you mention that when you maximized your browser then unity panel doesn't auto hide instantly. To solve this problem open compiz setting manager, go to unity section.

Increase Edge Reveal time, and select Hide launcher as auto hide. These option will quickly hide  your unity panel but will take time to reveal. Unity panel will hide instantly when it is not in use.

Comment: it does autohide though, when i mousover back sometimes, the launcher appears

Comment: Increase Edge Reveal time which makes delay to appear panel. Best solution is use "never hide". If your screen is small then reduce the icon size to lowest(32) from experimental tab.